# Java + MS Exchange: how to retrieve .msg files

Tags: java, email, exchange-server

I've created a Java program with which I can retrieve mail from an Exchange mailserver. Problem is: the mail is in EML format and I need the MSG format!

Right now I'm retrieving mail through the web access part of Exchange, using the Apache Slide project... is it possible at all to use java to retrieve msg files from an Exchange server?

I've seen examples of C# code, .NET code etc.. isn't it possible somehow to integrate these pieces of code with Java so I can use it to retrieve mail?

Greets,
Cesar

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in Java using Dmitry's RDO library, which is a sub-part of his Outlook Redemption library. See http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo/default.htm. The library builds on top of MAPI. You will need a COM library for this also for which I've used JACOB (Java COM Bridge). See http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/